# How do I find matching values within an array and store them in a new array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I can find duplicate values in an array, however the program gets stuck when I have more than 2 sets of duplicating values.

So for example, if I give the input:

```
10 1 2 3 4 5 10 10 10 10 10
```

(note the first digit [10] indicates how many numbers are in the array, and it is assumed all number will be in ascending order)

I get the correct score output of

```
Run {10,10,10,10,10} scoring 50.
```

(runCount (5) * runNumber (10) = 50)

If I have more than  2 repeating elements in the array, for example -

```
10 5 5 5 5 5 10 10 10 10 10
```

the scores are all muddled

```
 Run {5,10,10,10,10,5,5,5,5} scoring 45.
```

As the scores for {5,5,5,5,5} should be lower than {10,10,10,10,10}, ideally, the program would print the values with the highest score.

```
Run {10,10,10,10,10} scoring 50.
```

How do I make it so it only uses the highest values? I couldn't quite get the break function to work correctly.

Please let me know if you have any ideas? My code is below.

I can only use arrays, loops, and if/else

```
//Game that calculates the highest score based on array inputs

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_PLAYERS 13
#define TRIPLE 3

int main(void) {
int nPlayers, i, j, k;
int gameNumbers[MAX_PLAYERS];
int runCount, runCounter, runNumber, runScore;
int runScores[MAX_PLAYERS] = {0};

//read in numbers
scanf("%d", &nPlayers);
i = 0;
while (i < nPlayers) {    
    scanf("%d", &gameNumbers[i]);
    i = i + 1;
}

//Calculates Run Scores
//A run is when there are duplicates of the same number in a row
runCounter=0;
runNumber=0;
runScore=0;
j=0;
for (i=(nPlayers-1); i>=1; i--) {
    if(gameNumbers[i] - gameNumbers[i-1] == 0) {    //compares highest number to previous number to find equality
        runScores[j]=gameNumbers[i];                  
        j++;
        runCounter++;
        runCount=(runCounter+1);                          
        runNumber=(gameNumbers[i]);
        runScore=(runCount*runNumber);
    }
}

//Run Score
printf("runCounter:%d, runCount=%d, runNumber=%d, runScore=%d\n", runCounter, runCount, runNumber, runScore);
printf("runScores[]=");
i=0;
while (i<runCount) {
    printf("%d ", runScores[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("\n");

//Print run scores
printf("Run {%d", runNumber);                       
j=0;
    while (j < runCounter) {
        printf(",%d", runScores[j]);                //loop prints remainder of the stored run scores array
        j++;
        }
printf("} scoring %d.\n", runScore);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: First thought: did you check for "array index out of bounds" problems ?

Comment: I just initialised the array to set all values at 0, so I don't think I'm going out of bounds anymore. When I store the numbers in the array, it only seems to assign 4/5 numbers to the array, instead of all 5 matching numbers. I was able to just add in an extra variable (runNumber, and print that first, followed by the array elements. Is that the issue you meant?

Comment: What about debug it yourself?

Comment: You cannot do your job with a simple check like `if(gameNumbers[i] - gameNumbers[i-1] == 0)`. You should think, at least, to reset the counter each time you find a new different dup values is found.

Comment: and you must use,at least, an array to store all possible duplicates sum. Best will be done using dynamic allocation.

Comment: @LPs I'm pretty much limited to loops, arrays and if/else statements, could you please elaborate on the kind of check I should be doing?

Comment: You should use a "large enough" array to store all sum of repeated values. A the end you'll print the higher. The same for other values you have to print, like  `runCount` and so on.

Comment: @LPs Is there a way to store the first set of matching numbers in an array, and if there is a second, and a third set of matching numbers store them in their own arrays?
If I could do that, then I could run the calculations for each, and then compare and print the highest score. So in the case of 2 2 2 2 2 4 5 6 7 7, the 2's would beat the 7s?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110820/discussion-between-b-marino-and-lps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int numbers[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }

    int hi_score = INT_MIN, dupCount = 0 , theNumber;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int counter = 0, score;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n && numbers[i] == numbers[j]; ++j){
            ++counter;
        }
        if(counter > 0){
            score = (counter + 1) * numbers[i];
            if(hi_score <= score){//= : when 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5, 4 < 5
                theNumber = numbers[i];
                dupCount = counter + 1;
                hi_score = score;
            }
            i += counter;
        }
    }
    if(dupCount > 0){
        int new_array[dupCount];

        printf("Run {");
        for(int i = 0; i < dupCount; ++i){
            if(i)
                putchar(',');
            printf("%d", new_array[i] = theNumber);
        }
        printf("} scoring %d.\n", hi_score);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works EXACTLY how I want it to, however I can't use other libraries, just stdio.h and if/else, loops, and arrays.

Comment: @BMarino It is the value of the sequence given if not minus and not zero, there is no need. in that case Remove `#include <limits.h>` and change `hi_score = INT_MIN` to `hi_score = 0`

Comment: correction _not zero_ : zero is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Or try sth like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void generateScore(int*, int , int* , int* );

int main(){
    int number = 0;
    int times = 0;
    int array[10] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10};

    generateScore(array, 10, &number, &times);
    printf("number: %d \t times:%d", number, times);

    return (0);
}


void generateScore(int* array, int size, int* number, int* times) {
    *number = array[0];
    *times = 1;
    int i;
    for(i = 1 ; i < size && array[i] == *number; i++) {
        *times = *times + 1 ;
    }
    if(size <= i) {
        return;
    }

    int number2 = array[i];
    int times2 = 1;
    i++;
    for(; i < size; i++){
        if(array[i] == number2){
            times2 = times2 + 1;
        } else {
            if((*times * (*number)) < (number2 * times2)) {
                *times = times2;
                *number = number2;
            }
            number2 = array[i];
            times2 = 1;
        }
    }
    if((*times * (*number)) < (number2 * times2)) {
        *times = times2;
        *number = number2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[10] = {5 5 5 5 5 10 10 10 10 10};

generateScore(array, 10, &number, &times);
void generateScore(....){
  int sum=0;
  int preSum=0;
  int index=-1;
  int k;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   k=i;
   sum=0;
   while(((k+1)<size)&&(array[k]==array[k+1]))
    {
     sum=sum+array[k];
     k=k+1;
    }
   if(sum>presum){
    index=k-1;
    presum=sum;
   }
   i=k;
  }
var num = presum/array[index];
//now your sum in presum which is present num times in your array whose last index in array is index
}
```

for more [see here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/)